# how can i build a php mvc with libraries and helpers I'm looking for ideas

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

At this time I want to build a MVC framework. Everything is going fine but now I got a problem between controller and model

exemple about my problem

Model.php

```
class Model{
   public function __construct(){
        include('libraries/mysql.php');
        new mysql();
    }
}
```

and inside the mysql library i have a natural mysql method like select, insert, ...
now i want to use the mysql class inside my users_models by extending from Model

My user_model class

```
class user_model extends Model{
      public function get_user(){
           $this->mysql->select();
      }
}
```

result error cannot find select method ...

Comment: Don't instantiate like that. Look up something call Dependency Injection.

Comment: Please take some time and read [some great tips](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

Oh .. where to begin.

Lets begin with Model. In MVC the Model is not a class, but an application layer. It should be composed of *Domain Objects*, which are responsible for business logic. And the objects responsible for interacting with storage, usually - *DataMappers*.

Next .. well .. are you aware that there exist other (and actually better) databases beside MySQL? You seem to create some mysql object wrapper. What is the point? Especially when php has [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

As for the connections. Controller should have access to the a factory class, which creates "models". With database connection already injected in the object.

Comment: yes, abstract, abstract, abstract

Answer (score 1):

You dont want to include your lib in every instance. (if it really is a lib) just once.

```
require_once('libraries/mysql.php');

class Model{
   protected $_mysql;
   public function __construct(){
        $this->_mysql = new mysql();
    }
}

class user_model extends Model {
    public function foo() {
       $this->_mysql->select();
    }
}
```

If you want to use dependency injection as JohnP suggested, you will need a little more code. (untested, but should outline the way (yes, i know real DI works diffrent))

```
interface my_db {
 public function select();
 public function insert();
}

class mysql implements my_db {
 public function select() {
   // select code
 }

 public function insert() {
  // insert code
 }
}

class Model{
   protected $_db;
   public function __construct(my_db $DB){
        $this->_db = $DB;
    }
}

class user_Model extends Model {
    public function foo(){
       $this->_db->select();
    }
}

$model = new Model(new mysql());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   class Model{
       protected $mysql;
       public function __construct(){
            include_once('libraries/mysql.php');
            $this->mysql = new mysql();
       }
    }
```

Comment: you dont want to include the lib for every class instance

Comment: Edited, just use include_once instead